# Shimano V-Brake Loose cable at handle

Tags: shimano

The brake cable is loose at the brake handle.  Can it be fixed?  The metal end of the cable has pulled out of the little device that screws into the lever.

thanks,

ed marshall

Comment: Use your hands on the V Brake arms to pull the inner cable back through where it should be.  This is a super-temporary fix until the next time you brake.   Likely needs new cable inner and outers, and maybe your springs on the brake ARMs  are weak.

Comment: Other things that I've seen cause this, especially on cheap bikes that are left outside: sticking brake pivots (penetrating oil, maybe strip, clean and oil); sticky levers (clean, oil). These can both emulate weak springs or stiff cables

Answer (score 2):

I think you are saying that the brake *housing* has come out of the lever. It can simply be re-inserted back into the lever, however, if the cable was slack enough to allow this to happen in the first place, the brake needs to be adjusted properly.

Comment: Or it may be that the cable needs lubrication.